# How to remove colored EditText focus border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, focus

I wanted to remove the bottom `EditText` focus border on my `EditText`. I want it so that my `EditText` looks something like this:

[image]

That being said, I have looked online to make it so that the bottom focus color of the `EditText` is removed tried to set my `EditText` to `android:background="#00000000"` and also `android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"`. However, hte first hides the entire underline border (which I only want to hide the focus underline color, not the underline itself) and the latter makes my `EditText` a big white box. Is there any way to replicate what I want above? Thanks!

Comment: try android:background="@null"

Comment: @Nisarg that makes the entire bottom border of the `EditText` disappear though unfortunately. It's the same as setting the background to #00000000

Comment: try padding to achieve like in pic

Comment: @Nisarg but what about the bottom underline/border that separates each `EditText`?

Comment: check mine ans too if its helpful thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

**edittext_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!-- Draw a 1dp width border around shape -->
        <stroke
            android:color="#d3d3d3"
            android:width="1dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Draw only bottom border using background color  -->
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and apply background to Your `EditText` like

```
android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
```

Comment: This is perfect and works very well. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user1871869 always wc

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this, by putting it below edittext

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
```